# Awk parsing multiple gz files

Tags: shell, scripting

I am new to shell scripting and trying to grep some text in multiple gz files using awk. My code
    zcat log*.gz | awk{awk logic goes here}

but the above takes a lot of time to sift through prod logs.Is there any way to make it run faster?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use zcat and sed or awk to edit compressed .gz text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567685/use-zcat-and-sed-or-awk-to-edit-compressed-gz-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

You *might* see some output faster if you loop over the files instead of uncompressing them all at once:

```
for log in log*.gz; do
    zcat "$log" | awk 'awk logic goes here'
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script called [zawk](https://github.com/adamhotep/misc-scripts/blob/master/zawk) which can do this natively. It's similar to [glenn jackman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28351993/519360) but it handles `awk` options and several different compression mechanisms and input methods while retaining `FILENAME` and `FNR`.

You'd use it like:

```
zawk 'awk logic goes here' log*.gz
```