# Use zcat and sed or awk to edit compressed .gz text file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to edit compressed fastq.gz text files, by removing the first six characters of lines 2,6,10,14... I have two different ways of doing this right now, either using awk or sed, but these only seem to work if the files are unzipped. I would like to edit the files without unzipping them and tried the following code without getting it to work. Thanks.

Using sed:

```
zcat /dir/* | sed -i~ '2~4s/^.\{6\}//'
```

Using awk:

```
zcat /dir/* | awk 'NR%4==2 {gsub(/^....../,"")} 1'
```

Comment: You can't edit a compressed file in-place.  You have to uncompress it, edit it, and then recompress it.  Also, regardless of compression, `sed -i` won't work with a pipe - it has no way to write back that way.  Has to be a named file.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can't bypass compression, but you can chain the decompress/edit/recompress together in an automated fashion:

```
for f in /dir/*; do
  cp "$f" "$f~" &&   
  gzip -cd "$f~" | sed '2~4s/^.\{6\}//' | gzip > "$f"
done
```

If you're quite confident in the operation, you can remove the backup files by adding `rm "$f~"` to the end of the loop body.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a script called [zawk](https://github.com/adamhotep/misc-scripts/blob/master/zawk) which can do this natively. It's similar to [glenn jackman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28351993/519360) to [a duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28351625/519360), but it handles `awk` options and several different compression mechanisms and input methods while retaining `FILENAME` and `FNR`.

You'd use it like:

```
zawk 'awk logic goes here' log*.gz
```

This does not address sed's "in-place" flag (`-i`).